# Switch and do-while in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while, duffs-device

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 3, i=0;

    switch (n % 2) 
    {
    case 0: 
        do {
            ++i;
    case 1:
            ++i;
        } while (--n > 0);
    }
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Why is the output 5 and not 6 ? Can someone explain it to me more detailed ?

Comment: Look at [Duff's_device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: That's a variant of [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). Just never use code like that, and sites that uses such code shouldn't really be used for anything useful, except perhaps as an example of bad code.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code.  That will show you why the output is 5 and not 6.

Comment: If you want to know how it works, then read about Duff's device (previously linked) and step through it line by line in a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) while monitoring variables and their values to see what's really going on.

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- a `switch` statement isn't special; you can put a label inside its block and jump to that label from outside, just like any other block (except for a function body). And a `case` statement is just a label. That's why, for example, code without a `break` falls through to the next case. Both statements are far less expressive than they might seem.

Comment: Duff's device (see links above) is a method to implement loop unrolling, which is an optimization technique. It's definately not recommended to use such code without a very good reason (if at all).

Comment: Please explain your expectation of 6 as the result. Then answering by pointing out the misunderstanding our by providing reasonsing why you must have found an error in your compiler is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when you enter the 'switch' you jump inside the loop body. Then the loop is executed ignoring the label 'case 1'.

It is like executing the following lines of code.

```
++i;
--n;
++i;
++i;
--n;
++i;
++i;
--n;
```

I never suggest a code style like that, because it is harder to maintain. I prefer instead a [structured code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). The style of your example reminds me the [C64 Basic](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC) or [Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

While this code style is deprecable, the C language (C++ too) is flexible enough to allow you this. Take care because jumping randomly around could decrease the optimizer performance. At the end your code could run slower than the structured solution.

Answer (score 0):

as n%2 = 1
then after the switch statement yo go to the case 1 which is in do while, so you entered in the do while then these lines will be exectued

```
++i // then i = 1
--n // now n = 2 which is >0
++i // i = 2
++i // i = 3
--n // now n = 1 which is > 0
++i // i = 4
++i // i = 5
--n //  now n = 0 and does not satisfy the condition so the loop breaks and i = 5
```

Comment: *then these lines will be exectued* But why are they executed? What happened in the conditions to cause this "unexpected" behaviour? Without an explanation of why, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).